# How to find unique word in a single line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a string which is something like `50003 50003 50003 50001` this I get after processing into another file which is stored into a variable. now i want from that variable unique words. Like `50003 50001` how to do this?

Comment: Are you using `bash`, `zsh`, `python`, `c` (etc) ?\

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could pipe it through tr, sort, uniq, for example on command prompt you can test this:

```
 $ var1='50003 50003 50003 50001 50003'
```

Next,

```
 $ echo $var1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq
50001
50003
```

As you can see it outputs unique, and sorts it in case you want to do something with it later that requires sorted input.

### Update

For your additional question in comments, if you wish to save the results into a variable, you can, in script:

```
var2="$( echo $var1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq )"
```

- `$(` ... `)` is a bash command substitution, replacing the contents of `$(...)` with the commands' output

So later in your script if you wish to output `$var2` to the terminal, just:

```
echo "$var2"
```

- enclose `$var2` in quotes in order to continue to display it as one line per result
- otherwise without quotes, `echo` by default interprets each "word" in `$var2` as a separate argument, will output it one by one separated by space, so you end up with one long sentence instead.

Also remember you can save output to a file such as `~/unique_results.txt`:

```
echo $var1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq  > ~/unique_results.txt
```

- `>` is file redirection, redirects standard out to specified file

Comment: Above solution works but hot to store the value of echo $var1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq in a variable : var2=echo $var1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq does not work, echo $var2 is nothing

Answer (score 0):

If this is in bash, the following will print only the uniq words in a stored variable named `herpderp`:

```
for w in $herpderp; do echo $w ; done | uniq
```